# Does R have pivot table like python Dataframe have multiple index

Tags: r, dataframe

Does R have `pivot table` like python `Dataframe` have multiple index? 
Example :

```
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux  
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one   
A       0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412  2.565646  1.431256  1.340309 -1.170299   
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678  1.130127   
C      -1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 -2.211372  0.974466
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to look at `rpivotTable`, it will generate you `data.frame` to HTML view. here is the link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpivotTable/rpivotTable.pdf

```
library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable( iris, rows = c("Species"), cols = c("Sepal length","Petal length" ) )
```